# How to Read Data from RecyclerView and send in BottomSheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, bottom-sheet

I am using recyclerView to show list of apps installed in device

image - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6GIw.jpg)

and for more details I use bottomSheet on LongPress i.e. in ViewHolder Class, but **How to send data of selected tab to bottomSheet** with more details(such as package name, API level etc.)...for reference see images

I want - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAXVT.jpg)

I get from below coding - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC0mg.jpg)

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
    recyclerView.adapter = Adapter // I set adapter here with function getApps()
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

private fun getApps(): List<DataClass> {

    // here I get apps icon,name,size and return list<DataClass>
       
  return list
}
```

**Adapter.kt**

```
    class Adapter(private val listOfApps: List<AppData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(appView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(appView), View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener {

        init {
            appView.setOnClickListener(this)
            appView.setOnLongClickListener(this)
        }

        val icon: ImageView = appView.App_icon
        val name: TextView = appView.App_name
        val size: TextView = appView.App_size

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(v?.context, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean { 
         
           // I want here on Long press BottomSheet appears with details

            val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog()
            // Show bottomSheet on LongPress
            bottomSheetDialog.show(
                (v?.context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialog.tag
            )
            return true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.list_apps, parent, false
        )
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listOfApps.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentItem = listOfApps[position]
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(currentItem.icon)
        holder.name.text = currentItem.name
        holder.size.text = currentItem.size
    }
}
```

**BottomSheetDialog.kt**

```
    class BottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)

    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.RoundBottomSheetDialog
}
```

**DataClass**

```
    data class AppData(
    val icon: Drawable,
    val name: String,
    val size: String,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code the easiest solution would be:

1. Modify your BottomSheetDialog to include AppData in the constructor

   class BottomSheetDialog(val appData: AppData): BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

   ```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.RoundBottomSheetDialog
   ```

   }
2. Add onBind method inside your ViewHolder class:

   ```
    fun onBind(appData: AppData) {
        icon.setImageDrawable(currentItem.icon)
        name.text = currentItem.name
        size.text = currentItem.size
    }
   ```
3. Modify your onBindViewHolder method inside the Adapter to call that onBind method:

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
   holder.onBind(listOfApps[position])
   }
4. Inside your ViewHolder add `lateinit var currentItem: AppData` that will be set inside onBind and we can use it in `onLongClick`:

   class ViewHolder(appView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(appView), View.OnClickListener,
   View.OnLongClickListener {
   .
   .
   .
   override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {

   ```
        // I want here on Long press BottomSheet appears with details
        **val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(currentItem)**
        // Show bottomSheet on LongPress
        bottomSheetDialog.show(
            (v?.context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialog.tag
        )
        return true
    }

    **private lateinit var currentItem: AppData**

    fun onBind(appData: AppData) {
        **currentItem = appData**
        icon.setImageDrawable(currentItem.icon)
        name.text = currentItem.name
        size.text = currentItem.size
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

attach your `currentItem` list item to `ViewHolder` inside `onBindViewHolder` and inside `onLongClick` pass this data to freshly created `BottomSheetDialog`, which is extending `Fragment` (so you may use `Bundle` - `setArgument` method). then inside `onCreateView` set your data to `View`s

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an interface

   ```
    interface OnListItemClicked {

       fun onClicked(data : AppData)

     }
   ```
2. Implement that interface in BottomSheetDialog

   ```
    class BottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialogFragment(), OnListItemClicked  {

     override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
     ): View? {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)

    }

   override fun onClicked(data: AppData) {
     //show Details here
   }

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.RoundBottomSheetDialog
   ```

   }
3. Pass extra callback to the adapter from main activity.

   `Adapter(private val listOfApps: List<AppData>, val onClick: (AppData) -> Unit)`

Invoke the click listener from adapter with `listOfAppData[position]`

4. On MainActivity pass a function into the Adapter initialisation.

   ```
   fun passDataToBottomSheet(data: AppData) {

     val listener = OnListItemClicked()

     listener.onClicked(data)

    }
   ```

   `Adapter(list, ::passDataToBottomSheet)`

That's it. It should work now.